# Voice translator in python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, speech

I have used this code- https://github.com/Alekh-sinha/google_translator/blob/master/text_to_speech_3.py for doing voice translation.It basically converts speech to text then translate that text and then it converts translated text back to the voice. I wanted to use this for videos running on my PC so I enabled stereo mix in my PC and it worked. But when I applied same principal to skype call, it is not working.
I will be very grateful of somebody will help me in this

Comment: People may help you if you would give concrete details. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it but due to a different Python version it will not work. So it is beter to make a translator without API, it's codes are here but first go to your terminal and type pip install googletrans:

```
from googletrans import Translator

while True:
        sentence=str(input("say..."))
        translator=Translator()
        translated_sentence=translator.translate(sentence,src='en',dest='hi')
        print(translated_sentence.text)
```